# one hot encode with pandas get_dummies missing values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset in the form of a DataFrame and each row has a label ranging from 1-5. I am doing a one hot encode using `pd.get_dummies()`. If my dataset has all 5 labels there is not problem. However not all sets contain all 5 numbers so the encode just skips the missing value and creates a problem for new datasets coming in. Can I set a range so that the one hot encode knows there should be 5 labels? Or would I have to append `1,2,3,4,5` to the end of the array before I perform the encode and then delete the last 5 entries?

Correct encode: values 1-5 are encoded

```
arr = np.array([1,2,5,3,1,5,1,4])

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns = ['test'])
hotarr = np.array(pd.get_dummies(df['test']))

>>>[[1 0 0 0 0]
    [0 1 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 1]
    [0 0 1 0 0]
    [1 0 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 1]
    [1 0 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 1 0]]
```

Missing value encode: this dataset is missing label 4.

```
arr = np.array([1,2,5,3,1,5,1,])

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns = ['test'])
hotarr = np.array(pd.get_dummies(df['test']))

>>>[[1 0 0 0]
    [0 1 0 0]
    [0 0 0 1]
    [0 0 1 0]
    [1 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 1]
    [1 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up the [`CategoricalDtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#categoricaldtype) before encoding to ensure all categories are represented when getting dummies:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.array([1, 2, 5, 3, 1, 5, 1])

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['test'])

# Setup Categorical Dtype
df['test'] = df['test'].astype(pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
hotarr = np.array(pd.get_dummies(df['test']))

print(hotarr)
```

---

Alternatively can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) after `get_dummies` with `fill_value=0` to add the missing columns:

```
hotarr = np.array(pd.get_dummies(df['test'])
                  .reindex(columns=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], fill_value=0))
```

---

Both produce `hotarr` with 5 columns even though input does not contain 4:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0]]
```